# Sentencia SQL para obtener el ID de una entidad dado un nombre

Tags: java, jdbc

En SQL, tengo una tabla llamada `COMPANIAS` con `id_compania` y `nombre`.

Dado el nombre, en una variable, quiero encontrar el `id_compania` que tenga exactamente ese nombre.

Método para obtener el ID:

```
public int companiaNombreToInt(String nombre) {
        int id = 0;

        sSQL =  "SELECT id_compania FROM companias WHERE nombre = '" + nombre + "'";

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

            id = rs.getInt("id_compania");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: companiaNombreToInt()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        return id;
    }
```

Error:

> The result set has no current row.

He intentado:

- nombre = '%nombre%'
- nombre = '%+nombre+%'
- nombre = '+nombre+'

Cuál es la forma correcta?, o mi error es otro?.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La respuesta corta es que nunca llamas a `rs.next()`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código no está funcionando posiblemente debido a la forma de leer el resultado.  Aunque quiero aprovechar la respuesta para señalar que el mismo presenta fallos de seguridad.

1. Para consultas con criterios `WHERE` cuyos datos puedan venir del exterior, se recomienda el uso de `PreparedStatement`, para evitar la Inyección SQL.
2. Para leer los resultados, cuando son varias filas, conviene abrir un bucle, ya que `Resultset` devuelve un puntero, para irlo recorriendo registro a registro. En cualquier caso, **debes mover el resultset al primer registro**. Si quieres un sólo resultado puedes hacer un `if (rs.next()){...`

   La [documentación dice al respecto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> Un objeto `ResultSet` mantiene un cursor apuntando a su fila actual de
>   datos. **Inicialmente, el cursor se posiciona antes de la primera fila**.
>   El método `next()` mueve el cursor a la siguiente fila, y como
>   devuelve falso cuando no hay más filas en el objeto `ResultSet`, **puede
>   usarse en un ciclo `while` para iterar a través del conjunto de
>   resultados**.

3. Ten en cuenta que podrías obtener varios resultados que cumplan el criterio, ya que varias personas pueden tener el mismo nombre. Tratar de determinar un id único para un dato tan ambiguo como el nombre no es una muy buena idea.
4. Ten cuidado con los nombres de tablas y columnas, los cuales en algunos casos son *case sensitive* dependiendo del sistema operativo donde se vaya a usar la aplicación. O sea, no es lo mismo `COMPANIAS` que `companias`. Lo digo porque en la pregunta lo pusiste en mayúsculas, pero en la consulta aparece en minúsculas.

Aquí tienes una versión revisada.

```
public int companiaNombreToInt(String nombre) {
    int id = 0;

    sSQL =  "SELECT id_compania FROM companias WHERE nombre = ?";

    // Java 7 try-with-resources
    try (

         PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
         stmt.setString(1,name);
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sSQL);
        ) 
    {


        if (rs.next()) { //Para leer varias posibles filas se cambia el while por el if
            id = rs.getInt("id_compania");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e.getMessage(), "Error: companiaNombreToInt()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    return id;
}
```

Comment: En principio estoy de acuerdo con lo que dices, pero el bucle no tiene mucho sentido si se va a devolver un solo valor. Además, ya no usas la sintaxis `try-with-resources`, por lo que no estás cerrando el PreparedStatement ni el ResultSet, o sea crea un leak.

Comment: Editado @sstan no he cerrado la conexión, porque no sé si la necesitará en otra parte. Esto es un método que pide un id.

Comment: Disculpa la molestia, pero hay algunos puntos que aun necesitan corrección: 1) no estás asignanado el parámetro nombre en ninguna parte 2) Para obtener un `PreparedStatement` hay que llamar a `conn.preparedStatement(sql)`, no `conn.createStatement()`, y notarás que allí es donde se especifica el SQL, no en el `stmt.executeQuery()`, porque esto va a generar otro error. 3) No entiendo porque no dejaste la sintaxis `try-with-resources` tal como la tenía en la pregunta. Esa es la forma correcta y recomendada de cerrar el statement y el result set. Pero estoy de acuerdo con lo de la conexión.

Comment: Y un detalle mas, los nombres de tablas y columnas generalmente no son case sensitive, a menos que se rodeen de comillas dobles o las comillas especiales en MySQL por ejemplo.

Comment: En principio estoy de acuerdo contigo @sstan, pero no en todo. Los nombres de tablas que se escriban como deben escribirse. La cosa es mucho más ambigua de lo que crees, por ejemplo [esto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html): *names are not case sensitive in Windows, but are case sensitive in most varieties of Unix. One notable exception is OS X, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case sensitive. However, OS X also supports UFS volumes, which are case sensitive just as on any Unix*.

Comment: Admito que desconocía `try-with-resources`... sin embargo, revisando la documentación, dice que al usar esa metodología, no hace falta cerrar los recursos. Por [ejemplo aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html), dicen lo siguiente: *The following example uses a try-with-resources statement to automatically close a java.sql.Statement object:* y muestra un código que no llama a `close` en ningún momento.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta es que nunca llamas a `ResultSet.next()`. Si no llamas a `ResultSet.next()`, el result set que te devuelve la consulta está posicionada justo ***antes*** del primer resultado, de allí el error que recibes.

Parece que para un nombre dado, esperas recibir un solo `id`. Para que esto sea cierto, me imagino que has definido el campo `nombre` con un `unique constraint` en tu base de datos. Al menos, espero que eso es lo que has hecho.

De ser el caso, solo se trata de agregar una llamada a `rs.next()` y asegurarte de manejar el caso donde te devuelva `false`, o sea que no encuentra ningún registro con ese nombre. En el ejemplo que te dejo abajo, yo lanzo una excepción. Tu puedes decidir hacer algo diferente.

También, estoy de acuerdo con @A. Cedano de que no es correcto concatenar la variable `nombre` directamente en el SQL. Lo correcto es usar un `PreparedStatement`. Si lo sigues haciendo tal como lo tienes, prueba ponerle una comilla al nombre que buscas para que veas como te lanza otro error.

```
public int companiaNombreToInt(String nombre) {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id_compania FROM companias WHERE nombre = ?")) {
        stmt.setString(1, nombre);

        try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            if (!rs.next()) {
                throw new SQLException("No se encontró registro con el nombre: " + nombre);
            }

            return rs.getInt("id_compania");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: companiaNombreToInt()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por toda tu ayuda siempre. Tengo unas preguntas que me han dejado confundido. Por qué no usas el `ResultSet` justo debajo de `PreparedStatement` como lo tengo en mi post?. El query SQL solo va dentro de `prepareStatement(QUERY)`?, pensé que iba también en `executeQuery(QUERY)`. El return dentro del bloque `try-catch` me lanza error ya que el método no encuentra nada para retornar. Guiándome de tus consejos, mira cómo me ha quedado en [este enlace](http://oi63.tinypic.com/2cnwdcm.jpg), confírmame si está correcto. Qué largo se ha vuelto el código para una tarea tan simple, xD